# Adding startTimeZone and endTimeZone

Tags: powershell

Why can't I put in the timezone for my appointment booking?

```
try
{
    $Appointment = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment($service);
    $Appointment.Subject=$CalendarItem."Subject";
    $Appointment.Start=$calendarItem."StartDateTime";
    $Appointment.End=$calendarItem."EndDateTime";
    $Appointment.Resources.Add($CalendarItem."Resources");
    $Appointment.StartTimeZone="Tokyo Standard Time";
}
catch
{
    # If we fail to set any of the required fields, we will not write the appointment
    $NoError=$false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to specify after you've created the ExchangeService object.

```
try
{
    $Appointment = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment($service);
    $Appointment.Subject=$CalendarItem."Subject";
    $Appointment.Start=$calendarItem."StartDateTime";
    $Appointment.End=$calendarItem."EndDateTime";
    $Appointment.Resources.Add($CalendarItem."Resources");
    $Appointment.StartTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
}
catch
{
    # If we fail to set any of the required fields, we will not write the appointment
    $NoError=$false;
}
```

See the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633707(v=exchg.80).aspx):

> Specify the non-local time zone when you instantiate the
>   ExchangeService object that will be used to create the calendar item,
>   and do not set the StartTimeZone property and EndTimeZone property on
>   the calendar item

OR

> Set the StartTimeZone property and the EndTimeZone property on the calendar item.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am still not able to add in appointment. Im using O365.

Comment: I presume you are saving the appointment? `$Appointment.Save()`

Comment: yes. if no errors, this command will execute. $Appointment.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Calendar);

Comment: And why are you not able to add? Any errors? What happens after you save? I don't have access to O365, so unable to help right now.

Comment: failed to set startTimeZone into the calendar.

Comment: Have you tried setting when instantiating the EWS object? I've tested using Outlook and the appoiontment is created with Tokyo time.

Comment: how to set when instantiating EWS object? Im using impersonation to execute the command.